# How do I set up pipelineTriggers using a declarative Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a scripted Jenkinsfile you set up build triggers on 'up stream' projects by setting :

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([
        upstream(
            threshold: 'SUCCESS',
            upstreamProjects: 'UpstreamJob\master'
        )
    ])
])
```

How do I set up the equivalent pipelineTriggers using a declarative Jenkinsfile in a multibranch pipeline job?

If I put pipelineTriggers in the 'options' section I get the following error:

```
WorkflowScript: 20: Invalid option type "pipelineTriggers". Valid option types: [buildDiscarder, catchError, disableConcurrentBuilds, overrideIndexTriggers, retry, script, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, timeout, timestamps, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withEnv, ws]
```

Comment: FYI, we're using Jenkins 2.73.1

Answer (score 5):

It should not be in the 'options' but in the 'triggers' section.

Try:

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        upstream (
            threshold: 'SUCCESS',
            upstreamProjects: 'UpstreamJob\master'
        )
    }
}
```